# Wakeup device with using power button

Tags: android

Is there any way to to wakeup android device without pressing the power button / without using alarm Manager
for example ontouchlistener

Answer (score 2):

If the device has an open mobile data socket connection, incoming packets wake up the phone.

If the device is a phone, incoming calls or text messages wake up the phone.

Alarms scheduled in `AlarmManager` by other apps may wake up the phone, depending upon how they are configured.

An `OnTouchListener` most certainly **cannot** wake up the phone. For it to receive an event, the phone must already be awake.